# Error: How to serialize data from getStaticProps in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, frontend

I am trying to fetch data from an Api but for sorry i've received this Error:

Server Error
Error: Error serializing `.results` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE6VY.png)

Answer (score 1):

The props you're passing contain an object with a key of value `undefined`. A quick solution would be

```
return {
 props: {
   results: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(request.results)); 
 }
}
```

`JSON.stringify` will remove those undefined values. You can try it out in your browser console: `JSON.stringify({someKey:undefined})`